# how to use nohup command in the shell script

Tags: shell

I have  script slp.sh which is simply a sleep command .
I need to trigger this  script using another script called "trigger.sh" . after triggering  slp.sh , Need to check the status of slp.sh ( it is running or not )

for that I have used the  command "nohup sh slp.sh &" in the trigger.sh script but I am not able to monitor  the running status  of slp.sh  because the  script execution has been halted  as "nohup: appending output to `nohup.out' "

Answer (score 0):

`nohup` will terminate once `slp.sh` terminates, so you can simply check whether the `nohup` process is still alive.  You can do so using e.g. `kill -0`.  The following should work in practice (for bash, at least):

```
nohup sh slp.sh &
LASTPROCESS=$!
...
if kill -0 $LASTPROCESS; then echo still running; else echo has terminated; fi
```

Comment: if we use "nohup sh slp.sh >app.out 2>App.error &"   execution will continue to the next line .  then we can check if the process  "slp.sh" is still running or not